# Elegant way to check if a number is within the range of a circular modulo set?

Tags: javascript, math

My math vocab is really shaky but I know exactly what looking I'm for, so please forgive the title.

Say I have a circular set of numbers from 0.00 - 0.99. This means that the number wraps back to 0 when it equals 1. So `1` really equals `0` (or `1 % 1`) and `1.1` really equals `0.1` (or `1.1 % 1`).

Now, given a number in this set (`setPoint`), and a number that represents half of the length of a range (`halfRangeLength`), I want to see if a number (`number`) is within that range or not.

```
const isInSetRange = (setPoint, halfRangeLength, number) => {
    // Returns => boolean ... number is between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)

    return (number >= setPoint - halfRangeLength) && (number < setPoint + halfRangeLength)
}
```

So for example:

```
isInSetRange(0.5, 0.1, 0.45) 
// => true, 0.45 is between 0.4 and 0.6
```

Now, here's where the trouble lies.

**How do I achieve the following outcome on the edges of my number set?**

```
isInSetRange(0, 0.1, 0.95) 
// => true, 0.95 is between 0.9 and 0.1
```

and

```
isInSetRange(0.9, 0.2, 0) 
// => true, 0 is between 0.7 and 0.1
```

I really lack the math background to get into this. If someone can help in any programming language that shares a common Math library with javascript I'd greatly appreciate this.

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question properly. Why is `0 is between 0.7 and 0.1` and `0.95 is between 0.9 and 0.1` expected to be true? If they both are true, there is no condition in which your function will return `false`.

Comment: It's because the number wraps around at 0.  `isInSetRange(0.9, 0.2, 0)` tests that the number is `>(0.9-0.2)` or `<(0.9+0.2)-1`

Comment: Thanks all for the help! As a sidenote, does anyone have the vocabulary to describe this better in math terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shift the setPoint and value in the function if the halfRangeLength would cause a the low/high value to go outside the 0...1 range

Seems to work for the example data

```js
const isInSetRange = (setPoint, halfRangeLength, number) => {
    let low = setPoint - halfRangeLength;
    let high = setPoint + halfRangeLength - 1;
    if (low < 0) {
      setPoint -= low;
      number = (number - low) % 1;
    } else if (high > 0) {
      setPoint -= high;
      number = (1 + number - high) % 1;
    }
    return (number >= setPoint - halfRangeLength) && (number < setPoint + halfRangeLength)
}



console.log(isInSetRange(0.5, 0.1, 0.45))
console.log(isInSetRange(0, 0.1, 0.95))
console.log(isInSetRange(0.9, 0.2, 0))
```